# Find effect size of chi-squared data

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, effect-size, contingency-tables

I have data that looks like the following:

```
A <- c(2,20,2,7)
```

I want to do a post-hoc power analysis to check if my sample size is sufficient, but to do a power-analysis I need to know the effect size and when i do a chi-square i get the output

```
chisq <- chisq.test(A)
chisq
```

```
Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  A
X-squared = 27.968, df = 3, p-value = 3.689e-06
```

How do I find the effect size?

When I for instance do T-test or regressions in other contexts, I get an 'estimate' output as the effect size.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chi-square test is different from your t-test or regression, you are looking for deviations from the expected counts. If you check the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) :

> Pearson's chi-squared test is used to determine whether there is a
> statistically significant difference between the expected frequencies
> and the observed frequencies in one or more categories of a
> contingency table.

in this case what you are testing for is this, suppose we have a total count of 31 (sum(A) = 31) , and we split them into 4 bins, what is the probability of getting 2,20,2 and 7.

In this case, the null hypothesis is that each bin would have 31 / 4 = 7.75 counts.

You can see this in your test:

```
a$expected
[1] 7.75 7.75 7.75 7.75
```

According to [this reference from spss](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Chi-Square_Tests.pdf) and [this reference for R](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html), the effect size is:

```
p0 = rep(1/length(A),length(A))
p1 = A/sum(A)

w = sqrt(sum(((p0 - p1)^2)/p0))
w

0.9498343
```

Your effect size should be 0.9498343

Comment: Suppose that someone says that the sample size is too low to trust the data that shows that the distribution observed is significantly different from random distribution (null) - to answer this I would do a power analysis. To do this, I need to know the effect size. I do not know how I can find this in the output i get from my chi-square test in R.

Comment: could you read the answer in detail?  a power analysis is meant to test for a given alpha and effect size, the sample required. What are you testing from the chi.square test above? what are the numbers

Comment: If you tell explain what does the numbers mean, no one can tell you what is an effect size. there is no magic plug in here

Comment: The numbers are as you described, I have a total sample of 31 participants, i check for 4 different kinds of toothpaste (each participant use only one brand), 20 use brand A etc. Is the population equally distributed across brands or is a preference revealed?

Comment: See updated answer